# Can email senders figure out my catch-all email address by looking at the email headers?

Tags: email, email-address, catch-all

I want to set up a catch-email address, so that email to a non-existent account on my domain will go to this default address.

I know that you can access email headers for any email that's sent. Will people that send emails that end up getting forwarded to the catch-all email address be able to see what that catch-all address is?

Comment: As someone who thought he was clever having a catch-all email (in my early web days) I strongly advise against using random email addresses for anything meaningful.  You _will_ get spammed to death and when you decide to close your catch-all all those email addresses you created for fun or whatever, will stop working.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no".  I am not sure where you think people who send an email TO you are going to see email headers.

Comment: Yeah I don't know much about email headers. Thanks

Comment: Email headers is meta information that is included with each email.  It includes data about who sent the email, which server it was sent through, the route it took to get to you and much more.  Almost all email clients have a way to view headers, it is interesting stuff.  The headers are only included after an email is sent, that is why the sender never sees it.  However be aware that if you bounce an email, then the original sender may pick up some info, but you still have to bounce from a specific email address or the domain in general, it won't reveal if you have a catch-all.